# FXML Custom Chart

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml, netbeans-8

I've been using custom fitting chart from [Ensemble Test](http://fxexperience.com/2012/01/curve-fitting-and-styling-areachart/), which works great.

Problem is I cannot use it in FXML. [Someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396952/can-i-keep-integral-tick-marks-even-with-autoranging-on-an-axis) seemed to do that successfully.

Error: *Instances of curvefittedareachartappfxml.CurvedFittedAreaChart cannot be created by FXML Loader.*

**FXMLDocument.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import curvefittedareachartappfxml.CurveFittedAreaChart?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" fx:controller="curvefittedareachartappfxml.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="128.0" layoutY="25.0" text="Click Me!" />
      <AreaChart layoutX="56.0" layoutY="131.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="444.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="60.0">
        <xAxis>
          <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
          <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
        </yAxis>
      </AreaChart>
      <CurveFittedAreaChart layoutX="10.0" layoutY="160.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="444.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="250.0">
         <xAxis>
            <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
         </xAxis>
         <yAxis>
            <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
         </yAxis>
      </CurveFittedAreaChart>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**CurveFittedAreaChart.java** Original from Oracle Ensemble

```
 /*
 * Copyright (c) 2008, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
 * All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
 *
 * This file is available and licensed under the following license:
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *  - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *  - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *  - Neither the name of Oracle Corporation nor the names of its
 *    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
package curvefittedareachartappfxml;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.shape.ClosePath;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.PathElement;
import javafx.util.Pair;

public class CurveFittedAreaChart extends AreaChart<Number, Number> {

    public CurveFittedAreaChart(NumberAxis xAxis, NumberAxis yAxis) {
        super(xAxis, yAxis);
    }   
    @Override protected void layoutPlotChildren() {
        super.layoutPlotChildren();
        for (int seriesIndex = 0; seriesIndex < getDataSize(); seriesIndex++) {
            final XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = getData().get(seriesIndex);
            final Path seriesLine = (Path) ((Group) series.getNode()).getChildren().get(1);
            final Path fillPath = (Path) ((Group) series.getNode()).getChildren().get(0);
            smooth(seriesLine.getElements(), fillPath.getElements());
        }
    }

    private int getDataSize() {
        final ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> data = getData();
        return (data != null) ? data.size() : 0;
    }

    private static void smooth(ObservableList<PathElement> strokeElements, ObservableList<PathElement> fillElements) {
        // as we do not have direct access to the data, first recreate the list of all the data points we have
        final Point2D[] dataPoints = new Point2D[strokeElements.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < strokeElements.size(); i++) {
            final PathElement element = strokeElements.get(i);
            if (element instanceof MoveTo) {
                final MoveTo move = (MoveTo) element;
                dataPoints[i] = new Point2D(move.getX(), move.getY());
            } else if (element instanceof LineTo) {
                final LineTo line = (LineTo) element;
                final double x = line.getX(), y = line.getY();
                dataPoints[i] = new Point2D(x, y);
            }
        }
        // next we need to know the zero Y value
        final double zeroY = ((MoveTo) fillElements.get(0)).getY();
        // now clear and rebuild elements
        strokeElements.clear();
        fillElements.clear();
        Pair<Point2D[], Point2D[]> result = calcCurveControlPoints(dataPoints);
        Point2D[] firstControlPoints = result.getKey();
        Point2D[] secondControlPoints = result.getValue();
        // start both paths
        strokeElements.add(new MoveTo(dataPoints[0].getX(), dataPoints[0].getY()));
        fillElements.add(new MoveTo(dataPoints[0].getX(), zeroY));
        fillElements.add(new LineTo(dataPoints[0].getX(), dataPoints[0].getY()));
        // add curves
        for (int i = 1; i < dataPoints.length; i++) {
            final int ci = i - 1;
            strokeElements.add(new CubicCurveTo(
                    firstControlPoints[ci].getX(), firstControlPoints[ci].getY(),
                    secondControlPoints[ci].getX(), secondControlPoints[ci].getY(),
                    dataPoints[i].getX(), dataPoints[i].getY()));
            fillElements.add(new CubicCurveTo(
                    firstControlPoints[ci].getX(), firstControlPoints[ci].getY(),
                    secondControlPoints[ci].getX(), secondControlPoints[ci].getY(),
                    dataPoints[i].getX(), dataPoints[i].getY()));
        }
        // end the paths
        fillElements.add(new LineTo(dataPoints[dataPoints.length - 1].getX(), zeroY));
        fillElements.add(new ClosePath());
    }

    /**
     * Calculate open-ended Bezier Spline Control Points.
     *
     * @param dataPoints Input data Bezier spline points.
     * @return The spline points
     */
    public static Pair<Point2D[], Point2D[]> calcCurveControlPoints(Point2D[] dataPoints) {
        Point2D[] firstControlPoints;
        Point2D[] secondControlPoints;
        int n = dataPoints.length - 1;
        if (n == 1) { // Special case: Bezier curve should be a straight line.
            firstControlPoints = new Point2D[1];
            // 3P1 = 2P0 + P3
            firstControlPoints[0] = new Point2D(
                    (2 * dataPoints[0].getX() + dataPoints[1].getX()) / 3,
                    (2 * dataPoints[0].getY() + dataPoints[1].getY()) / 3);

            secondControlPoints = new Point2D[1];
            // P2 = 2P1 – P0
            secondControlPoints[0] = new Point2D(
                    2 * firstControlPoints[0].getX() - dataPoints[0].getX(),
                    2 * firstControlPoints[0].getY() - dataPoints[0].getY());
            return new Pair<Point2D[], Point2D[]>(firstControlPoints, secondControlPoints);
        }

        // Calculate first Bezier control points
        // Right hand side vector
        double[] rhs = new double[n];

        // Set right hand side X values
        for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; ++i) {
            rhs[i] = 4 * dataPoints[i].getX() + 2 * dataPoints[i + 1].getX();
        }
        rhs[0] = dataPoints[0].getX() + 2 * dataPoints[1].getX();
        rhs[n - 1] = (8 * dataPoints[n - 1].getX() + dataPoints[n].getX()) / 2.0;
        // Get first control points X-values
        double[] x = GetFirstControlPoints(rhs);

        // Set right hand side Y values
        for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; ++i) {
            rhs[i] = 4 * dataPoints[i].getY() + 2 * dataPoints[i + 1].getY();
        }
        rhs[0] = dataPoints[0].getY() + 2 * dataPoints[1].getY();
        rhs[n - 1] = (8 * dataPoints[n - 1].getY() + dataPoints[n].getY()) / 2.0;
        // Get first control points Y-values
        double[] y = GetFirstControlPoints(rhs);

        // Fill output arrays.
        firstControlPoints = new Point2D[n];
        secondControlPoints = new Point2D[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            // First control point
            firstControlPoints[i] = new Point2D(x[i], y[i]);
            // Second control point
            if (i < n - 1) {
                secondControlPoints[i] = new Point2D(2 * dataPoints[i + 1].getX() - x[i + 1], 2
                        * dataPoints[i + 1].getY() - y[i + 1]);
            } else {
                secondControlPoints[i] = new Point2D((dataPoints[n].getX() + x[n - 1]) / 2,
                        (dataPoints[n].getY() + y[n - 1]) / 2);
            }
        }
        return new Pair<Point2D[], Point2D[]>(firstControlPoints, secondControlPoints);
    }

    /**
     * Solves a tridiagonal system for one of coordinates (x or y) of first
     * Bezier control points.
     *
     * @param rhs Right hand side vector.
     * @return Solution vector.
     */
    private static double[] GetFirstControlPoints(double[] rhs) {
        int n = rhs.length;
        double[] x = new double[n]; // Solution vector.
        double[] tmp = new double[n]; // Temp workspace.
        double b = 2.0;
        x[0] = rhs[0] / b;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {// Decomposition and forward substitution.
            tmp[i] = 1 / b;
            b = (i < n - 1 ? 4.0 : 3.5) - tmp[i];
            x[i] = (rhs[i] - x[i - 1]) / b;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            x[n - i - 1] -= tmp[n - i] * x[n - i]; // Backsubstitution.
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

**Controller** and **App** files are default NetBeans generated.

Comment: Is the name of the package that the chart is in really `package`?  `package` is a reserved word in Java, you can't name a package `package`.

Comment: No, it's sth else, just renamed that for showcase.

Comment: Please don't do things like rename identifiers in pasted code, instead provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that somebody could copy and paste to replicate the issue.

Comment: Added the source files as requested.

Answer (score 1):

**What's going wrong**

There are multiple issues in your code.

1. If you want to instantiate a instance of a class by referencing it in FXML, the class needs to a have default (no-arg) constructor.

   Unfortunately, this isn't very well document in the [Introduction to FXML document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation).
2. If you wish to set properties of an instantiated class via FXML, that class needs to have appropriate getters and setters.  Refer to the property naming conventions used in the [JavaFX properties and binding tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm).  Adhere to the [conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.3-method-names) for [lower camel case](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.3-camel-case) method naming or FXML won't pick up your methods as settable properties.
3. You are trying to assign a CategoryAxis to the XAxis of your custom chart, but the custom chart type you supplied requires that the XAxis be a NumberAxis.
4. An exception to the first two rules is if you supply a builder class (a sample builder class is provided below).

**Sample builder class**

Here is the builder code for the AreaChart class, which allows it to be used in the FXML in the way in which you have used it.  If you wish to use your custom chart in the same way, you need to create your own builder.

```
package javafx.scene.chart;

/**
Builder class for javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart
@see javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart
@deprecated This class is deprecated and will be removed in the next version
* @since JavaFX 2.0
*/
@javax.annotation.Generated("Generated by javafx.builder.processor.BuilderProcessor")
@Deprecated
public class AreaChartBuilder<X, Y, B extends javafx.scene.chart.AreaChartBuilder<X, Y, B>> extends javafx.scene.chart.XYChartBuilder<X, Y, B> {
    protected AreaChartBuilder() {
    }

    /** Creates a new instance of AreaChartBuilder. */
    @SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public static <X, Y> javafx.scene.chart.AreaChartBuilder<X, Y, ?> create() {
        return new javafx.scene.chart.AreaChartBuilder();
    }

    private javafx.scene.chart.Axis<X> XAxis;
    /**
    Set the value of the {@link javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart#getXAxis() XAxis} property for the instance constructed by this builder.
    */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public B XAxis(javafx.scene.chart.Axis<X> x) {
        this.XAxis = x;
        return (B) this;
    }

    private javafx.scene.chart.Axis<Y> YAxis;
    /**
    Set the value of the {@link javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart#getYAxis() YAxis} property for the instance constructed by this builder.
    */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public B YAxis(javafx.scene.chart.Axis<Y> x) {
        this.YAxis = x;
        return (B) this;
    }

    /**
    Make an instance of {@link javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart} based on the properties set on this builder.
    */
    public javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart<X, Y> build() {
        javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart<X, Y> x = new javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart<X, Y>(this.XAxis, this.YAxis);
        applyTo(x);
        return x;
    }
}
```

**Sample code modifications**

I did a minor refactoring of your FXML and the Oracle custom chart code to allow you to reference it in FXML.  This code is just a sample to get you started, you will need to make more modifications to plot a useful chart in the manner you wish.

The sample does not take the custom builder class approach, instead it uses a default constructor and exposes the axes as properties.

In your CurveFittedAreaChart class, replace:

```
public CurveFittedAreaChart(NumberAxis xAxis, NumberAxis yAxis) {
    super(xAxis, yAxis);
}
```

with:

```
public CurveFittedAreaChart() {
    super(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
}
```

If you need to modify the axes (e.g., change their auto ranging capabilities), then you can inject the chart in your controller using @FXML, retrieve the axes from it in the controller initialize method, and modify the axes in code there.

In your FXML remove your axes specification, e.g., the chart is just referenced as below:

```
<CurveFittedAreaChart layoutX="10.0" layoutY="160.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="444.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="250.0">
</CurveFittedAreaChart>
```

[image: area chart]

**Related info on usage in SceneBuilder**

If you also want to use your custom component in SceneBuilder (which admittedly is not what your question asks), there are additional tasks you should perform:

- [How to create an FXML file for an already created new component in java than add it to scene builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444698/how-to-create-an-fxml-file-for-an-already-created-new-component-in-java-than-add)